# ESP-01 module drawing 3mA on Deep Sleep

Tags: esp8266

I'm trying to use the Deep Sleep feature of the ESP8266 with an inexpensive ESP-01 module. These need to be modified to bridge GPIO16 to RST, in order to wake up from deep sleep. 
Also, I have removed the power LED.

I'm using the Arduino implementation. The device enters deep sleep for the specified amount, and wakes up. 
The problem is: most specs state in this mode, current draw should be in the "sub-100uA" range. I'm seeing about 3mA.

I have lifted all pins, even the FLASH chip VDD, but I simply can't seem to reduce the current draw. I have measured with two different instruments and the current reads the same, about 3mA.

There is no regulator in the circuit as it's all running from a lab supply for now.

Comment: First things first, is your measurement solution (handheld multimeter? bench multimeter?) capable of reading in that range? A cheap handheld may have problems with burden voltage.

Comment: It's a Fluke 107. It's an  "electrician's multimeter". But the result is the same I'm getting with my DIY lab supply which has a MAX4080-based current meter. Both measure around 3mA

Comment: Is /CS being held high on the QSPI flash chip?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany interesting question and I did try that too. It's around 3V while Vdd is around 3.2V. I tried a 4.7K pullup between Vdd and /CS in the flash IC but nothing changed.

Comment: Do you have any signals asserted against a pulling resistor?  Are you applying I/O voltages to any powered-down chips?  Do you have any communication channels like a serial UART connected?   All of these can either cause power draw, or create misleading measurements (possibly even leading you to measure *less* than the actual power consumption).

Comment: Any floating inputs? Also, have  you tried another module?

Comment: When you write "most specs state in this mode..." do you mean for the *processor* itself? Or do you mean for the entire *module* that you have? There is a huge difference between the two. Do you have a schematic handy for the module you are using? It probably has a flash chip on it, as well as an oscillator module. If the oscillator module itself isn't being shut down, that by itself could easily consume the current you measure. (Darned things are usually run with a very *hot* class-A inverter and they suck way too much current.) I'd be looking very closely at the board.

Comment: Did you remove the power LED?

Comment: @Whiskeyjack yes, i removed it. though it's a tiny led with very little output. it only draws a few hundred uA

Comment: @jonk here's a schematic I found. https://www.itead.cc/media/wysiwyg/Products/ESP-01_Schematic.png I'm not completely sure it's exactly the same as mine is just a generic module. The oscillator is a crystal it seems, so it should shut down in this deep sleep mode. The datasheet for the flash chip (I don't remember the exact part number right now) says /CS high, it should take a couple uA. There's nothing else on that board other than a handful of passives.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany it doesn't seem, from most code examples I've seen, that I should worry about that. Seems the ESP.deepSleep() function call takes care of everything. At least in most code examples I've seen, no one cleans up anything before calling that. I don't have another ESP-01 but I'll try with an ESP-12F later.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I tried shutting down UART, Wire, and unplugging everything. Leaving only CS tied to VDD, and the rest of the module as-is (I start with everything connected, execute, and enter sleep. Once I'm in sleep, I disconnected everything but CS). No change in current.